# PHP Filesystem manipulation security concerns

Tags: php, filesystems

I am looking for best practices, modules, etc. to securely do file system manipulation via PHP application. The CMS-like application will not use a database, but instead the markdown files are placed in folders and are processed at display time. Therefore, there will be a lot of moving files around, renaming files, writing to files, etc.

I am looking to either find some libraries (e.g., equivalent to an ORM) that will help to manage such actions, input sanitization, moving files. etc. rather than start from scratch. If nothing like this is available, I would like a listing of best practices, etc.

So far I have only found [guidance from PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.php).

More information: The plan is to build a web based end-user interface which sits ontop of [Stacey](http://staceyapp.com/). I would have a test environment with the end user interface, and when changes are ready they are then synced to the production environment. This is a non-DB based system. Stacey is convenient to manage and work with from a developer standpoint, but user's don't want to work directly with markdown and move files, etc.

Also: Please limit the answer to PHP issues; server things like chrooting or locking down the server would be dependent upon the user's individual environment and needs. From a development standpoint, I want to focus on securing my distributed code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific libraries that do this -- the filesystem support in PHP is extensive so I'm not sure why they'd be necessary. You might be better off starting with an existing CMS and modifying it to do what you want -- however I understand that might not be possible. It also sounds like the sort of thing that should be using a database, but I guess you already know that.

I can't claim to know exact best practice, this is more general advice.

First, your web server -- and therefore your PHP scritps -- will be running as a certain user. This depends on your configuration and particular server as well as the underlying OS. Ideally you want to make sure this user only has access to the filesystem area that your using as storage. Deny all access to everywhere else apart from read-access to where it really needs (your scripts, etc) and read-write to the storage area. The exact way to do this depends on your system.

That's your last line of defense, do not rely on it, it's there as a safety net.

It's not clear exactly what will cause files to be renamed, moved, altered but it's a safe bet that it's from user input. Therefore you need to make sure you sanitize all user input, if their page name becomes a file name you want do not want to let some enter `../../index.php` as a page name and nuke your main site.

Always assume the worst case: a user who knows the internals of your system intimately and is aiming to do most damage. Do not rely on 'security by obscurity' or 'nobody will ever do that'.

What I would do (and have done before) is two fold. First wrap all the filesystem functions up into a class that provides the same functions as methods. The job of this class is to check that anything happening is allowed, that means it's probably going to have to read the paths and filenames and work out the location of the changes.

Secondly, sanitize all user input that could be malicious when it first arrives. You might want to look at using `escapeshellarg` or URL encoding, or something else depending on what your input is.

You also mention files are processed at run-time, if users are allowed to write scripts (or worse PHP that gets executed) then you have a lot more issues and may have a fundamental problem. But that's not clear from your question.

Hope that helps.